# Is there such thing as system images available in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'd like to use basic images like the ones in the menu of the alarm application. Are these images integrated in the Android SDK ? I didn't find any way to access them.

If not, do you know a good free library ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

C.Hamel

Comment: Note that the term "system image" in Android also refers to a version of the Android platform...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html is your answer

and than you access like this android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was pretty sure it existed but I couldn't find it on the android developer reference...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use image of android system then you can use that all image which are in android's system..
you just need to write `android.R.drawable` and you will get all image ...

```
android.R.drawable.btn_dialog
```

Comment: Just for info, the #monodroid equivalent of `android.R.drawable.btn_dialog` is `Android.Resource.Drawable.ButtonDialog` (http://docs.mono-android.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Look in your android-sdk folder, you will find folders for each version of android including all the system images. You can copy the images you need to your own ressource folder and use them from there.

Comment: I think it is bad practice as those images are built in in Android.

Comment: As long as you use them for the same purpose it doesn't matter if the file is in your ressources folder or in the sdk folder

Comment: Well, you basically duplicate those files ( putting them in your application resources when they are built in the phone ) which I consider a bad practice.